# Can node-restify paths work with swagger?

Tags: node.js, swagger, restify, swagger-node-express

The [node-restify](https://github.com/restify/node-restify) library allows paths like `/foo/:id`. Can swagger handle such paths? i.e. something like?

```
var getFoo = {
    'spec': {
        'description': 'foo library',
        'path': '/foo/:id',
        'summary': 'return foo by id',
        'type': 'string',
        'produces': ['application/json']
    },
    'action': getFooObject()
};
swagger.addGet(getFoo)
```

When I try this in my app, the `http://locahost:3001/api-docs` page looks like:

```
{
    apiVersion: "0.0.1",
    swaggerVersion: "1.2",
    apis: [ 
        {
            path: "/foo"
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried escaping the double-colon with a `\` character. But that didn't make a difference. Also tried replacing single quotes by double quotes. Still no difference. I am using the [swagger-node-restify](https://github.com/early-birds/swagger-node-restify) library which is a fork from [swagger-node](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-node) repository. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You're describing a swagger 1.2 project, which has multiple files to describe it.  You can read more about the swagger 1.2 specification here:

https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/1.2.md

Because of that, your API will not be described at the `api-docs` location.  It should be shown at `api-docs/foo` based on your description above.

note the `/api-docs` is called the Resource Listing and it points to the Api Declaration, which is hosted relative to `api-docs` as `/foo`.

Final note, swagger spec 1.2 is old and the tooling for 2.0 is much better.  Consider upgrading your project to [swagger-node](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-node) or other.

Comment: I am using a library swagger-node-restify. That's why the swagger version is 1.2. I will try to use swagger-node directly. Let's see.

Comment: I tried the path `http://localhost:3001/api-docs/foo`. It does exist, but doesn't have the specification for the getFoo function.

Comment: do you see `/{id}` as a path?